# How to read an SSRS generated Excel file?

Tags: c#, excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am trying to read an SSRS-generated Excel file using C# and it is giving me issues when trying to connect using OLEDB. I am using the connection string:

```
string connStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR={1};IMEX=1\";", this.Path, hdr);
```

The above works perfectly when I create an Excel sheet of my own but with an SSRS generated Excel sheet I am getting the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: External table is not in the expected format.

Is there a step I am missing somewhere?

Update: It seems to work when I delete the headers manually after it has been generated from SSRS. I am not sure why the headers will cause the error when trying to connect.

Comment: Check the header names if they contain any special characters or see if you have any blank column?

Answer (score 0):

I would export from SSRS as XML or CSV, rather than Excel.  You will get more consistent output.

Rendering to Excel is vulnerable to many layout quirks that will destroy your interface - e.g. nudge a text box by 1mm and it might insert a hidden column.